# How to lock Wordpress front-end with login and password?

Tags: login, front-end, user-access

I would like to lock whole WordPress site (all pages, all posts, whatever content I will add in the future) with login page same as for example it is made here (clear your cookies) http://facebook.com.

How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Absolute Privacy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/absolute-privacy/) plugin for your purpose.

This plugin turns your WordPress blog into a fully private site where you control who has access. It's perfect for family blogs, private communities, and personal websites. **You can lock-down the entire site** or create a members only area, moderate new registrations, force users to enter first/last name and choose their password during sign up, and more!

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to quickly password protect your WordPress site with a single password. This plugin only protects your WordPress generated content. It does not protect images or uploaded files so if you enter and exact URL to in image file it will still be accessible.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/

Answer (score 0):

You can force logging in by:

1. creating a function that redirects users to a login page,
2. creating a function that redirects users to the page originally requested, and
3. adding these functions to a custom plugin.

Step #2 is optional. But, it might be more user-friendly.

Use the code below in a custom plugin.

The *forced_login* function (with the call to *add_action()*) is for the first step. The *redirected_login* function (with the call to *add_filter()*) is for the second (optional) step.

### forced_login function

```php
/**
 * template_redirect Action Hook: Redirect non-logged in users to the login page by using
 *   the URL returned by the function wp_login_url().
 *
 * The custom query parameter 'login_redir' is used to redirect users to the page originally
 *   requested. This parameter is optional and can be removed if after logging in users should always
 *   be redirected to the default page. If removed, the if-statement would look like this:
 *   if ( wp_safe_redirect( esc_url( wp_login_url() ) ) )
 *
 */
function forced_login() {
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    nocache_headers();
    if ( wp_safe_redirect( esc_url( wp_login_url() . '?login_redir=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) ) {
      exit;
    };
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'forced_login', 10, 1 );
```

### redirected_login function

```php
/**
 * redirected_login Filter Hook: Update the 'redirect_to' parameter using the custom
 *   query parameter 'login_redir'.
 *
 * This function is optional. Use it if you want to redirect users to the originally
 *   requested page.
 *
 * @param string $redirect_to The default login redirect URL.
 * @param string $request The URL the user came from.
 * @param WP_User|WP_Error $user WP_User object if the login succeeded or
 *   WP_Error object if the login failed.
 *
 * @return string An updated $redirect_to parameter.
 *
 */
function redirected_login( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
  $query = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY );
  parse_str( $query, $params );
  $path = $params['login_redir'];

  if ( empty( $path ) ) {
    $redir = $redirect_to;
  } else {
    $redir = get_home_url() . $path;
  }

  return $redir;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirected_login', 10, 3 );
```

### Custom Plugin

If you have never created your own custom plugin before I'd suggest taking a look at the [WordPress Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/).

To get you started, create a basic plugin by creating a [PHP file with a header](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/#minimum-fields) that looks like this:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: NAME_OF_YOUR_PLUGIN
 */
```

Add the code above to this PHP file, and save the file in your WordPress installation at this location (this assumes Windows is used with a 'C' drive):

C:/inetpub/wwwroot/<wordpress_installation_root>/wp-content/plugins/NAME_OF_YOUR_PLUGIN/NAME_OF_YOUR_PLUGIN.php

Creating a basic plugin is explained under **Plugin Basics: Getting Started** on the [WordPress Plugin Basics](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/#getting-started) page. After having installed this file, you can log into WordPress as an administrator, go to the Dashboard and use the Plugins menu option to activate the plugin.